# Creating custom Cordova plugin that needs resources (.zip /.jpg)

Tags: cordova-plugins

I created a custom cordova plugin that needs a resource file to work, a *.zip* file and an image file to be precise *(.jpg)*.

**Firstly i don't know how and where to add them properly in the plugin.xml** *(do i need to add them with the `<source-file>` , `<resource-file>` or if there is another tag that i should use)*.

**Secondly i need to know the path of their location**, to use them in my code.

An example would be very helpful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hav efound solution to my question :

```
<resource-file src="FooPluginStrings.xml" target="res/values/FooPluginStrings.xml" />
```

To add any ressources.